# Show and Hide DIV's after 5000 seconds when .wpcf7-mail-sent-ok

Tags: javascript, jquery, addeventlistener, contact-form-7

I made a Contact Form 7 with a custom "Thank You!" message that appears after wpcf7mailsent.

I need it to reverse after seconds. My current code does not work:

```
addEventListener('wpcf7mailsent', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    document.querySelector('.qtWRP').style.display = 'none';
    document.querySelector('.inputBTMx').style.display = 'none';
    document.querySelector('.cap').style.display = 'none';
    document.querySelector('.qtWRP2').style.display = 'block';
});

wpcf7Elm.addEventListener( 'wpcf7-mail-sent-ok', function( event ) {
jQuery ( 'form.wpcf7form' )[1000].reset();
}, false );;
```

Appreciate any help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: There's nothing in there about 5000 seconds. Use `setTimeout()` to take action after a time delay.

Comment: 5000 seconds is almost an hour and a half. Is that really what you mean?

Comment: I updated it the code

Comment: how does the html of the form look like? how does the html of the message? is the element gone or just hidden after a submit? are the events you wrote being triggered?

Comment: Do you really have over 1,000 forms? Where does the index `[1000]` come from?

Comment: I added screen shots.

Answer (score 0):

Use `setTimeout()` at the end of the event listener to reverse all the `.style.display` changes.

```js
addEventListener('wpcf7mailsent', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  document.querySelector('.qtWRP').style.display = 'none';
  document.querySelector('.inputBTMx').style.display = 'none';
  document.querySelector('.cap').style.display = 'none';
  document.querySelector('.qtWRP2').style.display = 'block';
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.querySelector('.qtWRP').style.display = 'block';
    document.querySelector('.inputBTMx').style.display = 'block';
    document.querySelector('.cap').style.display = 'block';
    document.querySelector('.qtWRP2').style.display = 'none';
  }, 5000000);
});
```

Comment: I tried this and I lost the thank you message

Comment: I don't see how that's possible. The part that displays the thank you message is exactly what you wrote in your code. My addition doesn't run until 83 minutes later.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: No errors found

Comment: test it at kooraw.com in the footer. Email form